# Не запускается runserver в Django

Tags: django, ubuntu

````
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 78, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_user_agents/templatetags/user_agents.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..utils import get_and_set_user_agent
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_user_agents/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    cache = get_cache(USER_AGENTS_CACHE)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_user_agents/utils.py", line 14, in get_cache
    return caches[backend]
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 44, in create_connection
    return backend_cls(location, params)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 182, in __init__
    super().__init__(server, params, library=memcache, value_not_found_exception=ValueError)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 28, in __init__
    self._class = library.Client
AttributeError: module 'memcache' has no attribute 'Client'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/denis/Projects/api-main/TestMyAPI/testAPI/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/denis/Projects/api-main/TestMyAPI/testAPI/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 637, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 622, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 327, in run
    autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 41, in watch_for_template_changes
    for directory in get_template_directories():
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 14, in get_template_directories
    for backend in engines.all():
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_user_agents/templatetags/user_agents.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..utils import get_and_set_user_agent
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_user_agents/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    cache = get_cache(USER_AGENTS_CACHE)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_user_agents/utils.py", line 14, in get_cache
    return caches[backend]
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 44, in create_connection
    return backend_cls(location, params)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 182, in __init__
    super().__init__(server, params, library=memcache, value_not_found_exception=ValueError)
  File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py", line 28, in __init__
    self._class = library.Client
AttributeError: module 'memcache' has no attribute 'Client' ```
````

Comment: Сделайте `import memcache; print(memcache)` в каталоге с вашим проектом и покажите что отпечатает

Comment: @andreymal , я создал файл(py) в папке проекта вот что вывело:
`<module 'memcache' from '/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/memcache.py'>`

Comment: Кажется, у вас установлен неправильный memcache, попробуйте удалить его и установить другой https://pypi.org/project/python-memcached/

Comment: @andreymal , извините я навичёк в джанге, да в пайтоне тоже, можете подсказать как удалить из пайтона этот модуль ? (я на ubuntu сижу)

Comment: Я не знаю как и что вообще вы установили, но по симптомам могу попробовать предположить, что `pip uninstall memcache`

Comment: @andreymal, слушай может у тебя есть немного время мне помочь ? ну в дискорд там зайти, я знаю много прошу, но если у тебя сейчас нет дел, то буду очень рад 
P.S. я разобрался с проблемой в посте, мне сейчас нужно просто сконектить бд и django,  не хочет хотя я все правильно ввожу